# How can I show and hide dynamic divs triggered by dynamic buttons in Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular

I got this work using a click event and some plain javascript but I'm sure there is a better way for this.

I'm generating some dynamic rows and corresponding dynamic buttons using ngFor.

They look like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let section of data.order?.sections" id="{{section.class}}Detail" class="{{section.name | lowercase | removeAmpersand | removeSpaces }}">Random Text Here</div>
```

And then elsewhere on the page there is a list of anchor tags also generated using an ngFor:

```
<a (click)="showDetails($event)" id="{{section.name | lowercase | removeAmpersand | removeSpaces }}"><span class="icomoon icomoon-eye"></span> Detail/a>
```

My question is, what is the preferred way that I could show and hide the divs? Each of the divs starts off with a css property of `display: none` and I was hoping to just toggle that. Instead I'm just using the click event to run a function that gets the div id and then I have some pure javascript that looks like this:

```
myDiv.style.display = myDiv.style.display === '' ? 'block' : '';
```

What should I do that would be the preferred method?

Comment: Did you find an effective solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally add css classes to your elements.
Something like

```
<div class="standardclass" [class.additionalclass]="showFlag"></div>
```

where `additionalclass` is another css class that will only be added if the expression `showFlag` is true. It can be any js expression, not just a flag.

You can also use `*ngIf` to conditionally add or remove the element from the dom entirely.

Search for "Angular 2 template syntax"

Comment: how would this work for multiple divs? for example. I have a div with class hardware, and another with class service and finally one for solutions.

now, I have two buttons, one to show hardware and another for service and finally solutions, but each one is on a loop and is dynamicly generated. maybe this invoice doesn't have services but it does hardware and solutions. since i don't know in advance, it needs to be something that could be use to show it's respective section but not affect other sections.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you basically need a bunch of flags. If you create everything in a loop maybe an array of flags would work. If you create the buttons in an *ngFor you can get the index which you can use to index your flag array. It sounds pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a model for your sections, then bind the foreach to the model, and as part of the model you can have a boolean for visibility which you can use in your loop to decided to hide or show.

Your buttons would toggle the visible boolean, and you can then rely on Angular2 to update the ui as your model changes.

It would be a bit of work to change your code to this style, but the advantages would include cleaner html, potentially better maintainability and the ability to unit test.